# How can I fix my addToCart, removeFromCart, addToWishlist, removeFromWishlist functions

Tags: reactjs, algorithm, function, react-context

Hello guys I will share with you my context component.

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import useProducts from '../fetchApi/useProducts';

export const ShopContext = createContext(null);

const ShopContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { isLoading, products, } = useProducts();  // Api
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]); // Cart 
  const [quantityTotal, setQuantityTotal] = useState(0); //  Qiymetler
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState(""); //Searching
  const [sortBy, setSortBy] = useState('price'); // Filter
  const [wishlist, setWishlist] = useState([]); //Wishlist
   

  if (isLoading) {
    return "...Loading"
  }

  const sortProducts = (sortBy) => {
    const sortedProducts = [...products];
    if (sortBy === 'price') {
      sortedProducts.sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price);
    } else if (sortBy === 'title') {
      sortedProducts.sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title));
    } else if (sortBy === 'quantity') {
      sortedProducts.sort((a, b) => a.quantity - b.quantity);
    }
  
    return sortedProducts;
  };


  
  const increaseQuantityTotal = () => {
    setQuantityTotal((prevTotal) => prevTotal + 1);
  };
  const decreaseQuantityTotal = () => {
    setQuantityTotal((prevTotal) => {
      if (prevTotal > 0) {
        return prevTotal - 1;
      }
      return prevTotal;
    });
  };

  const handleSearch = (e) => {
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
  };
  
  const addToCart = (id) => {
    setCartItems((prevItems) => {
      const updatedCartItems = [...prevItems];
      const itemIndex = updatedCartItems.findIndex((item) => item.id === id);
      if (itemIndex !== -1) {
        updatedCartItems[itemIndex].quantity += 1;
      }
      return updatedCartItems;
    });
    increaseQuantityTotal();
  };
  const removeFromCart = (id) => {
    setCartItems((prevItems) => {
      const updatedCartItems = [...prevItems];
      if (updatedCartItems[id] !== undefined && updatedCartItems[id] > 0) {
        updatedCartItems[id] -= 1;
      }
      return updatedCartItems;
    });
    decreaseQuantityTotal();
  };

  const addToWishlist = (id) => {
    if (wishlist[id] !== undefined) {
      setWishlist((prevLists) => ([
        ...prevLists,
        {
          ...prevLists[id],
          isWished:true,
        }
      ]));
    }
  };
  const removeFromWishlist = (id) => {
    if (wishlist[id] !== undefined) {
      setWishlist((prevLists) => ([
        ...prevLists,
        {
          ...prevLists[id],
          isWished:false,
        }
      ]));
    }
  };

  const getTotalCartAmount = () => {
    let totalAmount = products.reduce((acc, product) => {
      if (cartItems[product.id] > 0) {
        return acc + cartItems[product.id] * product.price;
      }
      return acc;
    }, 0);
  
    const roundedTotal = Math.round(totalAmount * 100000) / 100000;
    return roundedTotal;
  };

  console.log(cartItems)


  const contextValue = {
    cartItems,
    addToCart,
    removeFromCart,
    products,
    isLoading,
    quantityTotal,
    searchTerm,
    handleSearch,
    sortBy,
    sortProducts,
    setSortBy,
    getTotalCartAmount,
    addToWishlist,
    wishlist,
    removeFromWishlist,
  };

  return (
    <ShopContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {children}
    </ShopContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ShopContextProvider;
```

I have some issues with my functions. I can not display my added items at cart because I guess it does not work right.

I am getting products from fakestoreapi, so it means my products array like this > [{id:1, title:"XXX", price:10$, description:"something", category:"gender", image:"https://something", rating:{rate:3.9,count:120}, quantity:0, isWished:false}, and etc(same as previous one)] so please help me to fix my addToCart, removeFromCart and same for wishlist

Comment: "I guess it does not work right." is not really a clear question? Do you get any error ? What part of the code exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: Not an error but full of bugs. Still thanks for your attention I solved all .